# Generic degenerate singularity of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand what a generic degenerate singularity of an ODE is.

In one dimension we may consider the ODE $\dot x = a_1 x + a_2x^2 + \cdots$. In this case it seems natural to me that if we assume/impose that $a_1=0$, which makes $x=0$ a degenerate singularity, the next generic condition is $a_2\neq0$. Am I correct then to assume that in one dimension a generic degenerate singularity is given by $\dot x= a_2x^2+\cdots$ with $a_2\neq0$?

What happens in higher dimensions? In the plane consider then $\dot x = Lx + h(x)$, where $L$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix and has at least one zero eigenvalue; also $h:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ with $h(0)=0$ and $Dh(0)=0$. What is then a generic condition for $h$? $D^2h(0)\neq 0$?

What is the formalism for this in general? would it be like "there is a $k>1$ such that $D^k(0)\neq 0$"? Would one need to prove this, or is it well-known ... can I find such a proof somewhere?

Comment: This looks like the exploration of normal forms of parameter-dependent families of ODE, looking for parameters where the normal form changes. Also known as "René Thom's [catastrophe theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophe_theory)" or more generally bifurcation theory.

Comment: Thank you, I see the relation.